# Brush stroke flood fill

Tags: c#, image-processing, flood-fill

Halo all!
I'm trying to recreate the Cut from PhotoDirector
https://youtu.be/GLNNCrp650Y?t=77

And after several remakes and approaches, this is where I'm at.
[Autofill](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6Df1.gif)

The base code is from here:
http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/TextureFloodFill

The base code is from a single click, use that color and grow-tests comparing the initial color sample against every other pixel, and stops the grow if it's not similar.

Since I need to sample multiple pixel (on a single brush stroke), I used the nested bool class to check (tried adding Colors to List and use List.Contains per pixel checked. SUPER slow. This is much faster)

In the current attached code I'm (back to) using RGB. I used HSBColor before but tried back to RGB because there are cases in HSB where if Sat is very low, or Brightness is too low/high, it's hard to compare neighboring Hue of that pixel.
I'm about to revert back to HSB and gonna add 2 more nested bool, 1 only Sat>Brightness (for samples with saturation < threshold, and still have brightness so basically grey values)
Another just brightness (for very dark/bright)
This way, when sampling, the low sat sample goes to the Sat>Bri bank, and the low/high Bri goes to the Bri bank.
When testing pixels, first check the Bri if it can skip the Sat/Hue check, or then check the Sat if it can skip the (complete) Hue check.

I haven't tried this (getting tired of going back n forth from HSB to RGB...), because I'm starting to think (part of) the problem is not in the pixel check, but also the **GROW check**.
PhotoDirector(PD) has a really good edge detection too, and somehow can take out the fragmenting issue I'm having.
In my code, I'm checking the next **ONE** pixel and stop/continue based on that. Maybe PD checks a **FEW** pixels ahead and if it's consistently different then it actually stops, and if it's only a few pixels of different then it just grows over them, thus takes out pixels.

Another thing that PD has is a grow limit bounding box-kinda feature. My code, even a small brush stroke and little sample, if it matches and can grow to the whole image, it will. PD got a limit max width/height of the growth. I tried on a uniform color image and it does fill in boxes.
I thought maybe PD's tolerance is set to over the limit BUT with this limiting bound box, it can produce a solid fill, but in my case if my tolerance is too high then it'll just grow over obvious edges (and continues to the whole image...)
So I haven't personally added this bound-box limit and wait til the actual fill is more stable especially near the brushed area.

**TL;DR**
In a "brush to sample, flood fill on brush click up" method like in PhotoDirector, how do they do it? Is it better sampling/pixel color testing? Or also a way they grow the pixel check?

abc

Thanks for reading!
Cheers,

Here's the relevant code, kinda a mess because it's still constantly changing..

```
public class GLookup
{
public bool[] bBools;

public GLookup(int num)
{
    bBools = new bool[num];
}

}

public class RLookup
{
public GLookup[] gLookup;

public RLookup(int num)
{
    gLookup = new GLookup[num];
    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        gLookup[i] = new GLookup(num);  
    }
}

}

 static void ResetLookup()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < Grid.Paint.Options.colorLookupRes; i++)
    {
        rgbLookup[i] = new RLookup(Grid.Paint.Options.colorLookupRes);
        rgbCheck[i] = new RLookup(Grid.Paint.Options.colorLookupRes);
    }
}

static void InsertLookup(Color32 rgb, float tol)
{
    int r = (int)(rgb.r/byteToLookup);// * Grid.Paint.Options.colorLookupRes);
    int g = (int)(rgb.g/ byteToLookup);// * Grid.Paint.Options.colorLookupRes);
    int b = (int)(rgb.b/ byteToLookup);// * Grid.Paint.Options.colorLookupRes);

    if(r == Grid.Paint.Options.colorLookupRes)
        r = Grid.Paint.Options.colorLookupRes - 1;
    if(g == Grid.Paint.Options.colorLookupRes)
        g = Grid.Paint.Options.colorLookupRes-1;
    if(b == Grid.Paint.Options.colorLookupRes)
        b = Grid.Paint.Options.colorLookupRes-1;

    if(rgbCheck[r].gLookup[g].bBools[b])
    {
        return;
    }
    rgbCheck[r].gLookup[g].bBools[b] = true;

    int tolNum = Grid.Paint.Options.maxTolNum;// (int)Mathf.Lerp(Grid.Paint.Options.minTolNum, Grid.Paint.Options.maxTolNum, tol);

    // Initial
    InsertLookupEntry(r, g, b);
    InsertNeighborSatBri(r, g, b, tolNum);

    // Hue fills
    int currentHue;
    // +- 5 hue if tol 1
    for(int i = 0; i < Grid.Paint.Options.hueFill; i++)
    {            
        // Higher hue
        currentHue = r + (i + 1);

        if(currentHue > Grid.Paint.Options.colorLookupRes-1)
            currentHue = Grid.Paint.Options.colorLookupRes-1;

        InsertLookupEntry(currentHue, g, b);
        InsertNeighborSatBri(currentHue, g, b, tolNum);

        // Lower hue
        currentHue = r - (i + 1);

        if(currentHue < 0)
            currentHue = 0;//            Grid.Paint.Options.colorLookupRes;

        InsertLookupEntry(currentHue, g, b);
        InsertNeighborSatBri(currentHue, g, b, tolNum);
    }
}
// This used to be for Hue/Sat/Brightness. But changed back to RGB, so this is similar as above's Hue tolerance fill

static void InsertNeighborSatBri(int r, int g, int b, int tolNum)
{
    int currentG;
    int currentB;
    for(int i = 0; i < tolNum; i++)
    {
        // Add the min plus from given value
        currentG = g + (i + 1);
        currentG = Mathf.Clamp(currentG, 0, Grid.Paint.Options.colorLookupRes - 1);
        for(int j = 0; j < tolNum; j++)
        {
            currentB = b + (j + 1);
            currentB = Mathf.Clamp(currentB, 0, Grid.Paint.Options.colorLookupRes - 1);
            InsertLookupEntry(r, currentG, currentB);

            currentB = b - (j + 1);
            currentB = Mathf.Clamp(currentB, 0, Grid.Paint.Options.colorLookupRes - 1);
            InsertLookupEntry(r, currentG, currentB);
        }

        currentG = g - (i + 1);
        currentG = Mathf.Clamp(currentG, 0, Grid.Paint.Options.colorLookupRes - 1);
        for(int j = 0; j < tolNum; j++)
        {
            currentB = b + (j + 1);
            currentB = Mathf.Clamp(currentB, 0, Grid.Paint.Options.colorLookupRes - 1);
            InsertLookupEntry(r, currentG, currentB);

            currentB = b - (j + 1);
            currentB = Mathf.Clamp(currentB, 0, Grid.Paint.Options.colorLookupRes - 1);
            InsertLookupEntry(r, currentG, currentB);
        }
    }
}

static void InsertLookupEntry(int r, int g, int b)
{
    rgbLookup[r].gLookup[g].bBools[b] = true;
}    

// Take in list of points from a single brush stroke
public static List<Point> FloodCutBrush(this Texture2D aTex, Color32[] refPixels, List<Point> growPoints, List<Point> lastDotSample, float tolerance, bool[] history, bool isAdd)
{
int w = aTex.width;

    int h = aTex.height;
    List<Point> changedPixel = new List<Point>();
    Color32[] photoPixels = new Color32[refPixels.Length];
    System.Array.Copy(refPixels, photoPixels, refPixels.Length);

    bool[] existCheck = new bool[history.Length];

    Queue<Point> nodes = new Queue<Point>();

    ResetLookup();

    // Setting up samples
    foreach(Point v in growPoints)
    {
        // Out of bounds is not valid
        if(v.x < 0 || v.y < 0 || w < 0)
            continue;

        int refId = (v.x) + ((v.y) * (w/2));
        if(refId >= photoPixels.Length)
            continue;

        Color32 hsb = photoPixels[refId];

        InsertLookup(hsb, tolerance);
        nodes.Enqueue(v);
    }

    // Fill search marks a pixel to alpha = 0. Then checks the top/bottom pixel and adds that to queue for future iteration
    while(nodes.Count > 0)
    {
        Point current = nodes.Dequeue();

//this goes right


for(int i = current.x; i < w / 2; i++)
        {
            int idx = i + current.y * (w / 2);
            if(idx >= history.Length)
                continue;

            Point fullCoord = IndexToPoint(w / 2, idx);
            // Because color sampling from brush is half resolution, and photopixel is full resolution..
            fullCoord.x *= 2;
            fullCoord.y *= 2;
            int fullIdx = fullCoord.x + (fullCoord.y * (w));

            Color32 C = photoPixels[fullIdx];

            if(history[idx] && (C.a == 0 || RGBTest(C) == false))// && (C.b < highBright && C.b > lowBright))
            {
                changedPixel.Add(current);
                existCheck[idx] = true;
                break;
            }

            C.a = 0;
            photoPixels[fullIdx] = C;
            // Queue up/down pix
            if(current.y + 1 < h / 2)
            {
                C = photoPixels[fullIdx + w];
                if(history[idx] && (C.a != 0 && RGBTest(C) == true))// || (C.b > highBright || C.b < lowBright))
                {
                    nodes.Enqueue(new Point(i, current.y + 1));

                }
            }

            if(current.y - 1 >= 0)
            {
                C = photoPixels[fullIdx - w];
                if(history[idx] && (C.a != 0 && RGBTest(C))) // || (C.b > highBright || C.b < lowBright))
                {
                    nodes.Enqueue(new Point(i, current.y - 1));

                }
            }

            changedPixel.Add(current);
            existCheck[idx] = true;

        }

        //this goes left, same as above but --x


    }

    return changedPixel;
}

public static bool RGBTest(Color32 c1)
    {
    int r = (int)(c1.r/ byteToLookup);
    int g = (int)(c1.g/ byteToLookup);
    int b = (int)(c1.b/ byteToLookup);

    if(rgbLookup[r].gLookup[g].bBools[b])
    {
        count++;
        return true;
    } else
        return false;

}
```

Comment: Is this a performance question?  Or is there some other issue?

Comment: It's an algorithm question. There's a big difference between my code and PD's result, my code lacks the things to solid-ly handle the fragments (without flooding over edges) in flood filling and I'd like to know what kind of approach to solve it. Performance-wise, these "sample nested color lookups" are doing really well, but even with the method to "fill in neighboring entries", it's still either fragment-ing so much or over flooding edges